# Text is not appearing in textarea n google chrome

Tags: zend-framework, browser

I am working in zend framework . When I am adding text in the form it saves the text in database but during edit the text is not shown for the textarea. If I replace the textarea with text box than I m able to see the text during edit.
I am facing this issue in google chrome. and in rest of the browsers it is working fine.

Comment: some code will be nice.

Comment: Are you using custom fonts?

Comment: no I am not using custom font.

Comment: No...javascript is used